# relocate the axes label in 3D plotting

Tags: plotting

How can I move the label $G \Lambda^2$ a little further in this plotting:

```
solu[x_?NumericQ, 
y_?NumericQ] := (z /. 
FindRoot[
2 (Pi^2)/(6*(x)) == (E^(-z^2)) - (z^2) (Gamma[0, z^2] + 
Log[(z^2)/(2*y)] + EulerGamma - 1) - (y) Pi/2, {z, 
1}])*(1086)
Plot3D[solu[x, y], {x, 3.780, 3.781}, {y, 0.05, 0.09}, 
PlotPoints -> {30, 40}, 
AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(G\[CapitalLambda]\), \(2\)]\)",
"Qe", "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(*\)]\)"}, 
LabelStyle -> {20, GrayLevel[0]}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: One option is to simply wrap the label in something like `Row@{Spacer[10],...,Spacer[10]}`

Comment: @LukasLang Where should I add that?

Comment: Simply replace your label by `Row@{Spacer[10],"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(G\[CapitalLambda]\), \(2\)]\)",Spacer[10]}` - you can also add whitespace characters manually (e.g. `"         \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(G\[CapitalLambda]\), \(2\)]\)        "`), but with feels at least a bit cleaner - the basic idea is simply to make the label take up more space, so that it's moved away from the axis a bit more

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks! It works well!

Comment: @LukasLang Could you add this as an answer? There's a high likelihood of this question remaining unanswered otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Converting my comment into an answer, as suggested</sup>

The most straightforward way to achieve this is to make the label take up more space. This way, the label is automatically placed further away from the axis, thus preventing any overlap with the tick-marks.

One way is to use [`Row`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html) together with [`Spacer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Spacer.html):

```
solu[x_, y_] := 1000 Sqrt@Ramp[(0.082 - y)]
Plot3D[
 solu[x, y], {x, 3.780, 3.781}, {y, 0.05, 0.09},
 PlotPoints -> {30, 40},
 AxesLabel -> {
   Row@{
     Spacer@15, 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(GΛ\), \(2\)]\)", 
     Spacer@15
    },
   "Qe",
   "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(*\)]\)"
   },
 LabelStyle -> {20, GrayLevel[0]},
 AxesLabel -> Automatic
 ]
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: For clarity, you are using `Row`in order to directly influence the position of the `AxesLabel` which will then allow reorientation of the `Plot3D` to change how the `AxesLabel` is displayed in-tandem with the reorientation? I.e. moving the plot will move the spaced out label as well?